# PowerShell Issue with Get-Content

Tags: windows, powershell, file-get-contents, remote-access, windows-console

I have an issue. When I run a command:

> powershell -command "gc C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQLServer\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG -totalcount 5

There is an error:

> "Get-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   argument 'Files\Microsoft'.  At line:1 char:3  + gc <<<<  C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG -to talcount 5 
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingException 
>   +FullyQualifiedErrorId:PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand"

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Always put your path between quotes when it contains spaces.

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQLServer\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG" -TotalCount 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using single quotes around the file path:

```
powershell -command "gc 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQLServer\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG' -totalcount 5"
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your path contains space characters (e.g. between *C:\Program* and *Files\Microsoft*), and powershell uses this as a delimiter between parameters. Try the following to group the path together as string:

```
powershell -command "gc 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQLServer\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG' -totalcount 5"
```